# Eclipse spits out "This method must return a result of type int"

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, methods, return

I am a new to coding in Java and I am struggling trying to understand why things don't work. I have a class called Geek.java and under it I have a whole bunch of methods. One of the methods I was asked to do for my class was to find the smallest integer of 3 integers.

```
public int smallest(int num1, int num2, int num3){
    if (num1 < num2){
        if (num1 < num3 ){
            return num1;
        }
    }
    if (num2 < num1){
        if (num2 < num3){
            return num2;
        }
    }
    if (num3 < num1){
        if (num3 < num2){
            return num3;
        }
    }
    else 
        return num1;
}
```

Ignoring logical errors, as I understand, there must be a default return value if none of the if conditions match which *should* be specified by the else. However, eclipse is still telling me it "must return a value of type int." I apologize if the answer to this has already been stated before, but I can't seem to find it.
Thank you,

Comment: Not all of your control paths are returning a value.

Comment: What if goes into one of the if that don't have corresponding else blocks? Nested ifs? What will happen then, what will your method return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to understand why thing don't work. It is because, not all of your control paths are returning a value.

If you change your code to this:

```
if (num1 < num2 && num1 < num3){
    return num1;
}
else if (num2 < num1 && num2 < num3){
    return num2;
}
else{ 
    return num3;
}
```

See, now all of the control paths will return some value.

But I don't prefer this way of finding lowest element. You can write a function `min`, which tells the minimum of the two numbers and then use that function to write this `smallest` function.

```
public static int min(int a, int b){
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

And now the function `smallest`:

```
public static int smallest(int a, int b, int c){
    return min(min(a, b), c);
}
```

Comment: Oh alright, so why is it that when I comment out the else statement and just leave return num1 at the end that no error is given?

Comment: Because in that case, still all control paths return a value.

Comment: having a return statement at the end means that if the flow came from across all of the `if-else` combinations to the end of the function, that return statement will return some value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have nested `if` statements and this can cause your code to not return a value:

```
if (num3 < num1) {
        if (num3 < num2) {
            return num3;
        }
    } else
        return num1;
```

In this case, let's say `num3 < num1` but `num3` is not less than `num2`, then your code will not return any value because the inner `if` condition (`num3 < num2`) does not have a corresponding `else` block.

Changing your code to something like this should work, as your control flow then has a clear flow, and would always return a value:

```
if (num3 < num1 && num3 < num2) {

        return num3;

    } else
        return num1;
```

Similar changes should be made to the other `if` statements.